# Import Flask from local library

Tags: python, flask, boto

I'd like to have all my libraries, flask and boto, stored locally within the project instead of installed globally. I'm having some trouble getting this to work. My file structure is as follows:

```
project/
    project/
        __init__.py
        libraries/
            flask/
            boto/
        views/
            ....
        modules/
            __init__.py
            ....
        templates/
            ....
        static/
            ....
    runserver.py
```

And the contents of the relevant files as follows:

## project/runserver.py

```
from project import app
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

## project/project/_ *init*_.py

```
from project.libraries.flask.flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import project.views.index
import project.views.login
```

## project/project/modules/_ *init*_.py

```
import project.libraries.boto.boto
```

The imports of both Flask and boto do not work. The error reports that the libraries can not be found.

What am I doing wrong? Is this file layout (trying to separate views into multiple files while keeping all libraries local) a good idea?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to do this you may be better off setting up a `virtualenv` environment.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `project/project/libraries/__init__.py` file.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the problem. but I also noticed I had to add a flask/__init__.py. Is that ok? Or should I just move the inner flask directory to the libraries folder.

Comment: I think that is up to your use case – do you want the flask project checked out there, or is it okay to only have the flask package?  Generally when I want to control dependencies, I use `__path__` extension in an `__init__` module.  For an example, look at [`pkgutil.extendpath`](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html?highlight=pkgutil#pkgutil.extendpath)